# Regex for strings in Bibtex

Tags: variable-assignment, bison, flex-lexer

I've trying to write a Bibtex parser with flex/bison. Here are the rules for strings in bibtex:

- Strings can be enclosed in double quotes "..." or in braces {...}
- In a string, braces can be nested
- Inside a string, the braces should be balanced (invalid string: {this is a { test})
- Inside an "internet" {}, you can have any characters. So this string is valid: {This is a string {test"} and it is valid}

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: That post was about differentiating entries and strings - both can start with a {}. This one is about a regex _after_ recognizing that it is a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse bibtex with flex+bison: revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305789/parse-bibtex-with-flexbison-revisited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you're going into the field of a text parser.  Surprisingly, nobody has made a bibtex library for Actionscript that I could find, so it's an interesting problem.  If you do make one, do the community a favor and open source it :)

It won't be easy to do since you essentially have to go character by character and check for the chars that you need and do logic around that.  However, I recommend you look at [as3corelib's implementation of the JSON parser](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json/JSONTokenizer.as) which is somewhat similar to what you're trying to accomplish.  You'll at least get an idea of how to do it using a tokenizer and it's a very good start on your project.

Good luck.

Comment: The JSON parser was my thought exactly. Highly recommended.

Comment: I think the question got tagged (by others) incorrectly. The OP tagged it with `flex`, which should have been `gnu-flex`. The `flash` and `actionscript` got added by someone else.